# is it true function & call it

Tags: winforms

```
private void calcu(double a,int x)
{
    a=Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Clear();
} 


private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    calcu(a,1);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: I second @griegs, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to assign the variable `a` from the `button26_Click` method in the `calcu` method?

If so, you need to change your code a bit:

```
private void calcu(out double a, int x)
{
    a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Clear();
} 


private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double a;
    calcu(out a, 1);
    // Do something with `a`
}
```

Better yet, why not make it a function?

```
private double calcu(int x)
{
    var a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Clear();
    return a;
} 

private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double a = calcu(1);
    // Do something with `a`
}
```

Comment: +1, i like yours better.  plus i think you were just seconds before me

Answer (score 0):

```
private void calcu(double a,int x)
{
    a=Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Text = "";
} 


private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    calcu(a,1);
}
```